# How to execute graph-api Facebook Android SDK to upload photo and tag people?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to execute graph-api Facebook Android SDK to upload photo and tag people?
On web there is a lot of confusion with facebook sdk for android.

My first approach

```
Bitmap img = bitmap;
    if (img != null) {
        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), img, uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("message", "Winner @[" + uid1 + "] Second @[" + uid2 + "] Terzo @[" + uid3 + "]");
        // add more params here
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
```

but it doesn't  tag people 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I summarized my question above because I posted 2 questions without response . 
So I solved my problem and I am posting a solution to help another people of stackoverflow comunity.

To upload photo on facebook using facebook sdk 3.5:

1. To be sure to aver the right persmission "publish_actions","user_photos"
2. know that you have to upload photo before and tag people after.

To Upload photo on facebook

```
    ... //put update method where you need

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    Bitmap img = .... //your bitmap
    if (img != null) {

        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), img, uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("message", "my personal massage");
        // add more params here
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
   ...

private String idUploadResponse;
Request.Callback uploadPhotoRequestCallback = new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        if (response.getError() != null) {
            // post error
        } else {
            idUploadResponse= (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("id");
            if (idUploadResponse!= null) {

                String fbPhotoAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=" + idUploadResponse;
                tagPeople();


            } else {
                // error
            }

        }
    }
};
```

**idUploadResponse** is the photo id on facebook.

with the idUploadResponse you can tag friends. 
**uid1** variable conteins the id of user (get from facebook).

```
public void tagPeople(){

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("to", uid1);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    final String requestId = idUploadResponse +"/tags";
    Request request = new Request(session, requestId, params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("Error", error.getErrorMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    Request.executeAndWait(request);
 }
```

**To tag multi user**

```
protected void tagPeople() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    String multiTag= "[{'tag_uid':'"+uid1+"'} ,{'tag_uid':'"+uid2+"'}, {'tag_uid':'"+uid3+"'}]";
    params.putString("tags", multiTag);
            ....
}
```

Comment: How to give appropriate permission?

Comment: thank u soo much for posting the answer..god bless u :)