# Facebook sdk image posting failed

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post image on my wall via my app. It's working well with http links, but I need to post post image from my local phone memory.

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpeg");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("caption", "test");
bundle.putString("url", photo.toURI().toString());
if ( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null) {
     new GraphRequest(
               AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
               "/<user_id>/photos", bundle,
               HttpMethod.POST,
               new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                      public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            /* handle the result */
                            Log.i("<<FB=====>>", response.toString());

                      }
               }
     ).executeAsync();
}
```

But it's not working getting the following response

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 324, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#324) Missing or invalid image file}}
```

Now how can I attach a file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20998517/5216567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're uploading from local memory, passing in the uri is not enough. You should use the `newUploadPhotoRequest(AccessToken, String, File, String, Bundle, Callback)` method in the GraphRequest class.

Comment: +1 got it from here , https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/#newUploadPhotoRequest